# Create a catch-all handler for all events and delegates in C#

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, cil

I want to create a handler that can be used to handle any event or delegate.  Specifically, I want to be able to write code like below:

```
class Invoker
{
    public object Invoke(object[] arg)
    {
        // generic handling code
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var p = new Person();
    p.AddHandler("Event1", new Invoker().Invoke);
}
```

`AddHandler` is an extension method for `object` which receive an event name and a delegate of type `Func<object[], object>`.  It should be able to do whatever magic to bind the event (e.g. `Event1` in this case) to the provided delegate so that the delegate is invoked whenever the event is fired.

The signature of `Event1` shouldn't matter because `AddHandler` should work with all types of events (and delegates).

I suspect this might involve some CIL generation to build a dynamic delegate matching the type of the specified event (e.g. `Event1`) and forwarding the call to the specified delegate (e.g. `new Invoker().Invoke`).  I was able to build such a dynamic delegate, however it could only forward to static methods, not instance methods because I couldn't find a way to push the bound instance of the to-be-invoked method into the CLR stack (i.e. the `Invoker` instance in the example).  See the code provided below to see this issue clearly (see the line marked with ISSUE).

If anyone could point out a way to improve the dynamic generation code to capture bound object or better yet, suggest a simpler solution which doesn't need CIL then it is much appreciated.

```
public static void AddHandler(this object target, string fieldName,
    Func<object[], object> func)
{
    var eventInfo = target.GetType().GetEvent(fieldName);
    if (eventInfo != null)
    {
        Type delegateType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        var dynamicHandler = BuildDynamicHandler(target.GetType(), delegateType, func);
        eventInfo.GetAddMethod().Invoke(target, new Object[] { dynamicHandler });
    }
}

public static Delegate BuildDynamicHandler(this Type delegateOwnerType, Type delegateType, 
    Func<object[], object> func)
{
    MethodInfo invokeMethod = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    Type returnType = invokeMethod.ReturnType;
    bool hasReturnType = returnType != Constants.VoidType;
    var paramTypes = invokeMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
    var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("add_handler",
                                            hasReturnType ? returnType : null, paramTypes, delegateOwnerType);

    var il = new EmitHelper(dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator());
    if (paramTypes.Length == 0)
    {
        il.ldnull.end();
    }
    else
    {
        il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object[]));
        il.ldc_i4(paramTypes.Length);
        il.newarr(typeof(object));
        il.stloc_0.end();
        for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            il.ldloc_0
                .ldc_i4(i)
                .ldarg(i)
                .boxIfValueType(paramTypes[i])
                .stelem_ref.end();
        }
        il.ldloc_0.end();
    }

    /////// ******************  ISSUE: work for static method only
    il.call(func.Method); 
    if (hasReturnType)
    {
        il.unbox_any(returnType).ret();
    }
    else
    {
        il.pop.ret();
    }
    return dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(delegateType);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context as to why you want to do this?

Comment: @SimonC: I'm building an interpreted language which could interop with .NET.  I want to hook up functions written in that language to .NET events, e.g. clrObject.someEvent += func() {...}; where the right-hand side is a pure function from my language.  One way to do that is having the interpreter create a generic handler and add it to clrObject.someEvent so that later when the event is fired, the generic handler is invoked (which would in turn use the interpreter to execute the function).  I'm not sure if there's an alternative solution for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an implementation using expression trees:

```
    public static Delegate BuildDynamicHandle(Type delegateType, Func<object[], object> func)
    {
        var invokeMethod = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
        var parms = invokeMethod.GetParameters().Select(parm => Expression.Parameter(parm.ParameterType, parm.Name)).ToArray();
        var instance = func.Target == null ? null : Expression.Constant(func.Target);
        var converted = parms.Select(parm => Expression.Convert(parm, typeof(object)));
        var call = Expression.Call(instance, func.Method, Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), converted));
        var body =
            invokeMethod.ReturnType == typeof(void) ? (Expression)call : Expression.Convert(call, invokeMethod.ReturnType);
        var expr = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, parms);
        return expr.Compile();
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  This is much elegant than the CIL approach I use.  I think I need to get rid of my habit of immediately using CIL emit for any runtime code gen task.  Can you recommend any articles, books, and/or tools to help with expression tree programming?

Comment: @Buu - I learned by just playing around with the API.  It's pretty straightforward, and you can always inspect expression trees generated by the C# compiler if you're wondering how to express something.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using expression trees (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)?  They make it much easier to generate IL.

Comment: I'm aware of exp tree.  However, I think it doesn't matter which code-gen mechanism selected, the issue remains the same.

Comment: The answer from kvb proved that you're right, I should have looked at expression tree before considering reflection emit. The expression tree approach is much more straightforward and I would probably have not encountered the issue I had in the first place should I use it. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution.  I blogged about it with the full code [here](http://www.buunguyen.net/blog/a-catch-all-net-delegate-and-event-handler.html), in case anyone interested in the pure CIL generation approach (which is **not** as elegant as kvb's approach).