# Creating a catch-all delegate

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates

I am implementing a function that needs to pass a specific delegate type that is unknown at runtime. I would like to return a generic method that takes a ParamArray as its only argument (that method will be used to Invoke another method, passing the ParamArray for its arguments).

When using a 'real' delegate, the following code works fine:

```
Public Sub OnEvent(ParamArray params()) 
    'Do work
End Sub

Function SomeFunc()
    Return New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf OnEvent)
End Function
```

This works even though OnEvent doesn't match RoutedEventHandler's arguments - the compiler is ok with the ParamArray, and passes the arguments properly.

However, when using CreateDelegate, the runtime complains that the param's don't match:

```
Function SomeFunc()
   Return [Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(RoutedEventHandler), Me, "OnEvent")
End Function
```

The actual code will be getting the delegate type at runtime, so I need to use CreateDelegate. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Would `GetType(Object())` work?

Comment: No, because the AddHandler routine waiting for the Delegate requires an exact match

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? This seems like a dangerous way to program. Let's get some more information on your ultimate goal and maybe we can help you find a better solution than dynamic delegate creation.

Comment: @siride. I'm writing a MarkupExtension for wpf - it is set on the event 'property' of an element, and is returns a valid delegate for that event. It will bind to a given method signature on the data model. However, the magic in between doesn't know about the delegate type until runtime. [Also, I'm trying to return the catch-all delegate to the element, and will internally pass the event raised to the target. This allow for a dynamic target - if the object in the data-model changes, I don't need to detach the old target and attach the new one]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written the following code based on an answer to a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658765/create-a-catch-all-handler-for-all-events-and-delegates-in-c-sharp?rq=1), modified for VB and a little more concise:

```
Imports System.Linq.Expression.Expressions 'this might only work in VS2015. You can use a explicit name instead, i.e. Expressions.Call, Expressions.Lambda

Public Shared Function GetDynamicDelegate(delegateType As Type, method As Action(Of Object())) As [Delegate]
        Dim invokeMethod = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke")
        Dim params = invokeMethod.GetParameters.Select(Function(p) Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name)).ToArray
        Dim instance = If(method.Target Is Nothing, Nothing, Constant(method.Target)) 'Pass Nothing when Shared            
        Dim body = [Call](instance, method.Method, NewArrayInit(GetType(Object), params))
        Return Lambda(delegateType, body, params).Compile
End Function
```

(The original an extra line casting to Object() but that's done automatically, so I left it out)

This function only takes method As Action(..). You could implement it as func as Func(...), but then it will ONLY take a function for that argument.